# Каким членом предложения является слово "два"?

Tags: синтаксис, падежи, синтаксический-разбор

Каким членом предложения является и в каком падеже стоит слово "два"?

**Я была на юге два раза.**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Я была на юге два раза.**

**РАЗ** – в зн. сущ. 1. (обычно со сл., обозначающими количество). Указывает **на кратность действия**. Несколько, много раз.    Семь раз отмерь, один раз отрежь.

**Два раза** – количественно-именное сочетание, два – главное слово, управляет существительным, задает ему Р.п.

В то же время глагол управляет числительным ***два***, задает ему В.п.

В предложении ***два раза*** является неразложимым сочетанием **в роли обстоятельства** меры (сколько, как часто).

Answer (score 1):

В данном предложении "два раза" является обстоятельством (отвечает на вопрос *сколько?*).

> Имя числительное, обозначающее количество, в сочетании с
>   существительными является одним членом предложения:
>   Два дерева росли на опушке. Спектакль начинается в шесть часов.
>   (http://school-assistant.ru/?predmet=russian&theme=chislitelnoe_chast_rechi)

Comment: Вы пропустили вопрос про падеж. Было бы хорошо, если бы вы ответили на него.